# How to make videos play automatically from many videos using dynamic dom arrays?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, css-selectors, html5-video

How to make videos play automatically from many videos using dynamic dom arrays?

At the moment I am still using the html video element manually instead of the javascript array.

```js
var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
var video2 = document.getElementById('video2');
var video3 = document.getElementById('video3');
var imagen1 = document.getElementById('imagen1');

function imgTransition(){
    imagen1.style.opacity=0;
    video1.play();
    video1.style.opacity=1;
}
video1.onended = function(){
    video2.play();
    video1.style.opacity=0;
    video2.style.opacity=1;
}
video2.onended = function(){
    video3.play();
    video2.style.opacity=0;
    video3.style.opacity=1;
}
video3.onended = function(){
    video3.style.opacity=0;
    imagen1.style.opacity=1;
    window.setTimeout(imgTransition, 5000);
}
```

```css
*{padding:0;margin:0}video{width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;object-fit:cover;transition:all 1.2s linear;z-index:-10}.video1{opacity:1}.video2{opacity:0}.video3{opacity:0}.imagenes{opacity:0;transition:opacity 2s;width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;object-fit:cover;z-index:-10}.container{width:100%;height:100%}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <video autoplay  id="video1" class="video1">
        <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video   id="video2" class="video2">
        <source src="https://hunzaboy.github.io/Ckin-Video-Player/ckin.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video   id="video3" class="video3">
        <source src="https://www.cssscript.com/demo/vanilla-js-custom-html5-video-player-pureplayer/360.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <img src="transition.gif" class="imagenes" id="imagen1">
</div>
```

How to make videos play automatically from many videos using dynamic dom arrays?

How to dynamic the function:
`video.onended = function(){..}` ?

Comment: unclear what you are trying to do... do you want to have one video on screen and change the source from a dynamic array or...?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, yes I do, I want one video on screen and change the source from a dynamic array using transition css

Comment: I just tried `var source = 'http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small,https://hunzaboy.github.io/Ckin-Video-Player/ckin,https://www.cssscript.com/demo/vanilla-js-custom-html5-video-player-pureplayer/360';var arr = source.split(',');var total = arr.length;for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {var video = document.createElement("video");
 video.id = 'video'+i;
 video.setAttribute("class", 'video'+i);
 if(i==0){
 video.setAttribute("autoplay", 'autoplay');
 }video.innerHTML = '<source src="'+arr[i]+'.mp4" type="video/mp4">';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(video);
};`

Comment: How to dynamic the function: `video.onended = function(){..}` ?